# my Cubit is getting called when I move away from screen throwing an error on me

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  HomeCubit(this.repository) : super(InitHomeState());
  HomeRepository repository;


 

  getStatusCount() async {
    DashboardRequest request = DashboardRequest();
    request.userId = Prefs.getString(PrefsConstants.USER_ID);
    request.platform = 'm';
    request.obuIdList = [];
    DashboardResponse response = await repository.getStatusCount(request);
    if (response.statuscode == 200) {
      emit(StatusCountState(response.data!));
    } else {
      emit(StatusCountState(DashboardDetails()));
    }
  }
```

**cubit is getting called when navigated to new screen throwing an error this is the error:

Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close
E/flutter (26820): #0      BlocBase.emit (package:bloc/src/bloc_base.dart:97:9)
E/flutter (26820): #1      HomeCubit.getAlertCount (package:ialert/feature/home/cubit/home_cubit.dart:43:7)
E/flutter (26820):

**

I tried to close the cubit in on dispose method but it did not work. I want to see no error when navigating to new screen

Comment: Please add some more code about where your are using this cubit and how you are navigating to new screen.